# rails 3 validators & i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, validation

so i just started using the custom validators in rails 3, however i am not sure if i can use my existing activerecord i18n locale files.  it seems that i have to do

```
record.errors[attribute] << I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.{model}.attributes.{attribute}.invalid_whatever') if ...
```

instead of before when i could have just done

```
:message => :invalid_whatever
```

is there shorthand i can use in my ActiveModel:Validator/EachValidator class to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally found the answer...

```
record.errors.add(attribute,:invalid_whatever)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you end up reading this question (which by the time of this writing is a few years old), you could try the following for Rails 4:

**In your model:**
`class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :date, date_in_present: {message: :custom_message}
end`

**In your validator:**
`class DateInPresentValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if(value.to_date >= Date.today)
      true
    else
      object.errors[attribute] << options[:message]
    end
  end
end`

**In your i18n yml file:**
`en:
  activerecord:
   errors:
     models:
       document:
         attributes:
           date:
             custom_message: Date is not in present`

I didn't test this thoroughly.

You could also specify a fallback message in the custom validator:
`object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "Display this message if message is not in options")`